# How to upload a file in window forms?

Tags: winforms

In window forms, how to upload a file, I did not found any file upload control. Can you give me any reference? I want to store the document with in my systems drive. Thank you.

Comment: Where you want to upload?.........

Comment: in my system C drive, In asp.net generally we use file upload to store the doc in solution. so is there any way to store doc in c or d drives

Comment: 'upload' to local drive??? what a question

Comment: @Ssasidhar: Please clarify your question. People are answering in all kinds of direction, because it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Voting to close.

Comment: Mr. Paul i have one register form in my window application, in that user can upload his photo. Now i want to save that photo in solution folder or his drive.

Answer (score 24):

You can put on your form button and create click handler to it with the following code:

```
private void buttonGetFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Text files | *.txt"; // file types, that will be allowed to upload
    dialog.Multiselect = false; // allow/deny user to upload more than one file at a time
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // if user clicked OK
    {
        String path = dialog.FileName; // get name of file
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding())) // do anything you want, e.g. read it
        {
                // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use OpenFileDialog, here is a link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984392%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: not a valid url

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to this tutorial for raw HTTP POST:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Reference to WebClient class of .NET:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

A simple HTTP POST can be done like this:

```
string Upload_File_Content = ...;
string Url = ...;

using (var Http_Client = new WebClient()) {
  var Post_Data = new NameValueCollection();
  Post_Data["upload_file"] = Upload_File_Content;

  var Response = Http_Client.UploadValues(Url,"POST",Post_Data);
}
```