# I want to upload files with a C# windows forms project to a webserver

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I want to create a C# application using windows forms that let me upload files to a webserver, i have seen a lot of tutorial and everyone of them prove to be useless to solve my problem.

and with my project i have the next code in the button for upload

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UploadFile("http://localhost:8080/", location);
```

from here i had have several errors, an try multiple ideas, some of my more common errors are 404 not found or innaccessible path, also sometimes it doenst display me an error and works but the file doesn't save in the indicated path.

some of the links i use to solve the problem are the next ones:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/UploadwithCSharpWS05032007121259PM/UploadwithCSharpWS.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/8180/

[How to upload a file in window forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968138/how-to-upload-a-file-in-window-forms)

Comment: Code you've show is really all you need on WinForms side... You also need server that expects upload, correct file location and correct destination url - but it is very unclear what kind of error you are facing from your post.

Comment: if i use that code, it actually run the program but it doesn´t save the file in the indicated location, i tried to change it to C:\ but it happens the same thing
i will try with the parameters you have tell me and see if i get some result thanks

Answer (score 2):

upload a file to FTP server using C# from our local hard disk.

```
private void UploadFileToFTP()
{
   FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.server.com/sample.txt");

   ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
   ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
   ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

   byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\sample.txt");
   ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
   using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
   {
        s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
   }

   FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

   if (ftpResp != null)
   {
         if(ftpResp.StatusDescription.StartsWith("226"))
         {
              Console.WriteLine("File Uploaded.");
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In windows:

```
private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();    
    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.OK) return;              
    Upload(openFileDialog.FileName);
}

private void Upload(string fileName)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var uri = new Uri("http://www.yoursite.com/UploadMethod/");  
    try
    {
        client.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        client.UploadDataAsync(uri, data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In server:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> UploadMethod()
{
    var file = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    var fileName = Request.Headers.GetValues("fileName").FirstOrDefault();
    var filePath = "/upload/files/";
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath) + fileName, file);           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignored
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: in server side where i suppose add code in my project .

Comment: What if the server side is PHP, not ASP?

Answer (score 0):

winform

```
string fullUploadFilePath = @"C:\Users\cc\Desktop\files\test.txt";
string uploadWebUrl = "http://localhost:8080/upload.aspx";
client.UploadFile(uploadWebUrl , fullUploadFilePath );
```

asp.net create `upload.aspx` as below

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + file.FileName));
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you use an ASP.net??
for more context of my problem i can download without an asp.net
and i would like to not use asp.net for upload, only if is really necessary to solve my problem

Comment: +1. @user3353954 - you need something that accepts POST HTTP requests on `localhost:8080`. ASP.Net is broadly used HTTP stack in C# community (as it comes with .Net framework/Windows) so most samples for HTTP handling you'll see are using ASP.Net. Definitely you can use any other HTTP server - there is absolutely nothing ASP.Net specific in POST request send by `UploadFile`.

Answer (score 0):

you should set in win app

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

string fileName = "File Address";
Console.WriteLine("Uploading {0} to {1} ...",fileName,uriString);

// Upload the file to the URI.
// The 'UploadFile(uriString,fileName)' method implicitly uses HTTP POST method.
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```

then set  read and write permission for SubDir

Answer (score 0):

create a simple API Controller file in the Controllers folder and name it UploadController.

Let’s modify that file by adding a new action that will be responsible for the upload logic:

```
 [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public IActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _host.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = "";
                string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, name + ext);
                int counter = 2;
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    fileName = name + "(" + counter + ")" + ext;
                    fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                    counter++;
                }
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

We are using a POST action for the upload-related logic and disabling the request size limit as well.
and use code below in Winform

```
 private void Upload(string fileName)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var uri = new Uri("https://localhost/api/upload");
        try
        {
            client.Headers.Add("fileName", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            client.UploadFileAsync(uri, directoryfile);
            client.UploadFileCompleted += Client_UploadFileCompleted;
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Client_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("done");
    }
```

Goodluck