# get a file by the name the user puts into a textbox

Tags: c#, forms, text

I am new to C# and was wondering how to get a file by the name the user puts into a text box, then load that data into an array and display each item in the array into separate text boxes to then be edited and saved to that file again

[image]

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TextBox[] textBoxes;
        private Button[] buttons;
        private const string fileName = (getFile.Text);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
            buttons = new Button[] { button1, button2, button3, button4 };
        }

        private static void ReplaceLineInFile(string path, int lineNumber, string newLine)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                lines[lineNumber] = newLine;
                File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
            }
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFile();
        }

        private void LoadFile()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                WriteAllLines();
                return;
            }

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            if (lines.Length != textBoxes.Length)
            {
                // the number of lines in the file doesn't fit so create a new file
                WriteAllLines();
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                textBoxes[i].Text = lines[i];
            }
        }

        private void WriteAllLines()
        {
            // this will create the file or overwrite an existing one
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, textBoxes.Select(tb => tb.Text));
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save line 1
        {
            ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, 0, textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save line 2
        {
            ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, 1, textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // save line 3
        {
            ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, 2, textBox3.Text);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save line 4
        {
            ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, 3, textBox4.Text);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save all
        {

            Button button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null)
            {
                int lineNumber = Array.IndexOf(buttons, button);
                if (lineNumber >= 0)
                {
                    ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, lineNumber, textBoxes[lineNumber].Text);
                }
            }

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // get file
        {
            if (File.Exists(getFile.Text))
            {
                //shows message if testFile exist 
                MessageBox.Show("File " + getFile.Text + " Exist ");
            }
            else
            {
                //create the file testFile.txt 
                File.Create(getFile.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("File " + getFile.Text + " created ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use OpenFileDialog for geting file name

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12968709/966932, it might help you with `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: I dont want to open an explorer window. if the file is there then the content gets loaded into an array, if the file is not there then it makes the file and the user can add to that file

Comment: Is it essential that you edit each line separately?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about button click events. Button1Click doesn't make sense trying to follow your code.

Comment: no it's not essential that you edit each line separately

Comment: comment of what the buttons do now added to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place a `TableLayoutPanel` control onto your form. This will help easily placing the other controls.

Dock this panel where you want, then Edit the columns and set the `SizeType` for both columns to `AutoSize`. Set `AutoScroll` to true. Leave the control with the default name `tableLayoutPanel1`.

Now change the methods. Remove all `buttonX_Click` methods and paste this code instead of the existing `LoadFile`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    // Clear the existing rows
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // Add a new row
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

        // Create the TextBox
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();

        // Add any initializations for the text box here
        txt.Text = lines[i];

        // Create the button
        Button btn = new Button();

        // Add any initializations for the button here
        btn.Text = i.ToString();
        // Handle the button's click event
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        // This value helps the button know where it is and which TextBox it is associated to
        btn.Tag = new object[] { i, txt };
        btn.Width = 30;

        // Add the controls to the created row
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt, 0, i);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn, 1, i);
    }
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object[] btnData = (object[]) ((Control) sender).Tag;

    // The values are inside the sender's Tag property
    ReplaceLineInFile(fileName, (int)btnData[0], ((TextBox)btnData[1]).Text);
}
```

UPDATE: This is the whole source of the class, corrected:

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string fileName;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReplaceLineInFile(int lineNumber, string newLine)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                lines[lineNumber] = newLine;
                File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void LoadFile()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            // Clear the existing rows
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                // Add a new row
                tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

                // Create the TextBox
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();

                // Add any initializations for the text box here
                txt.Text = lines[i];

                // Create the button
                Button btn = new Button();

                // Add any initializations for the button here
                btn.Text = i.ToString();
                // Handle the button's click event
                btn.Click += btn_Click;
                // This value helps the button know where it is and which TextBox it is associated to
                btn.Tag = new object[] { i, txt };
                btn.Width = 30;

                // Add the controls to the created row
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt, 0, i);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn, 1, i);
            }
        }

        void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object[] btnData = (object[])((Control)sender).Tag;

            // The values are inside the sender's Tag property
            ReplaceLineInFile((int)btnData[0], ((TextBox)btnData[1]).Text);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save all
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                lines.Add(((TextBox)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i * 2]).Text);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines.ToArray());
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // get file
        {
            fileName = getFile.Text;
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                //shows message if testFile exist 
                MessageBox.Show("File " + fileName + " Exist ");
            }
            else
            {
                //create the file testFile.txt 
                File.Create(fileName);
                MessageBox.Show("File " + fileName + " created ");
            }

            LoadFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like what you did there though I still need the user to input a file name that can be searched for in a specific place then the data loaded into the text boxes.

Comment: Isn't `getFile` put there for this reason?

Comment: It's not loading the data from the text file name the user imputed

Comment: It's nothing to be sorry about. Everyone was a noob sometime. The important thing is that you learn something new everyday :)